# Как на веб-странице отобразить метаданные mp3-файла?

Tags: php, html

Работаю над проектом, связанным с аудиофайлами и столкнулся с проблемой.
В проекте необходимо через php вывести метаданные mp3-файла, а именно исполнителя.
К сожалению, как сделать это я не нашёл, быть может я плохо искал или такое в принципе не осуществимо.

Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь сможет ответить или перенаправить на нужный ресурс с ответом.

Comment: вот консольная id3ed https://github.com/lukasschwab/id3ed
запускай через exec / passtru
форматируй вывод и используй

Comment: их там может и не быть в принципе. Ну и если операция не одноразовая. то лучше подобнеые вещи хранить где нить в базе отдельно от самого файла, то есть считывать мету и сохранять при заливке самого файла